# JSPM - System - text plugin, remove whitespace

Tags: jspm, systemjs

When I use the text plugin of JSPM - System JS - like in the following code:

```
import dashboardTpl from './dashboard.tpl.html!text';
```

I get a string similar to this:

```
'<div class="bug" ng-class="{\r\n        \'closed-bug\' : bugCtrl.statusCode == 90,\r\n \'sev-one\':'
```

Is there an option for the plugin to remove white-space?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible by means of the text plugin (see source https://github.com/systemjs/plugin-text/blob/master/text.js). There are two options here:

1. create your own text plugin which additionally removes whitespace
2. remove whitespace in js after you import the text